# How to match up to double closing curly braces not followed with a curly brace

Tags: python, regex, string

So, I have a RegEX equation and line of code that removes all curly braces from a string, but I want it to only remove the brackets when they are balanced

here is my line:

```
matches = re.findall(r'{{(.*?)}}', url)
```

string example: {{location.city}}
output: location.city

But let's say the input string is:

```
{{location.city}}}}
```

I want the output to be `location.city}}`

I've been messing around with RegEx for a while and still haven't figured out how to do it.

Comment: Balanced brackets is not a place where the standard library `re` module is specialy good. You might want to have a look at the extended [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) one from PyPI that supports recursive matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may require no `}` after the closing `}}`:

```
re.findall(r'{{(.*?)}}(?!})', url)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h33eGB/1/)

The `(?!})` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `}` immediately on the right.

If the same is required with `{{`, if there can be no `{` before the `{{` at the start, add a lookbehind:

```
re.findall(r'(?<!{){{(.*?)}}(?!})', url)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h33eGB/3).